# How to count number of elements in json array stored in MongoDB collection

Tags: json, mongodb

I have mongodb collection "mongocollection", each document in the collection consists of two columns, first a string "cid" which is the id of the collection and second is a json array.

Ex:

```
{ "_id" : "domain.com", "
className" : "UserAgents", 
"userAgents" : [                
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-CA; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5",
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.6) Gecko/20100628 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)",
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090803 Firefox/3.5.2 Slackware",
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64) Gecko/2008072820 Firefox/3.0.1"
        ]
}
```

From mongo cmd line, i can get the contents of a given document within a collection as

```
db.CorruptUserAgents.find({"_id":"domain.com"}).pretty();
```

How do i get the number of elements in a given array of a given document. Ex

```
SOMETHING.count();
100
```

Is it possible to do this via cmd line ? 
I know i can get the document, iterate over the array and count the elements, but i want to do this from cmd line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.findOne()` instead since you are looking up by `_id`, it will return a single document.

So you can simply do something like this:

```
var document = db.CorruptUserAgents.findOne({"_id":"domain.com"});
var count = document.userAgents.length;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do i display the contents of count & document variable from mongo command line?

Comment: Also is it possible to know if the the values in the array are all unique ? if not how do i get the duplicate values in the array ?

Comment: The mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript shell... So you can pretty much do anything.  You could write a small function to get the duplicates if you want!

Comment: Got It. Had to just enter count and press enter

Comment: Answering the question for completeness.

{
db.CollectionName.findOne({"_id":"domain.com"}).userAgents.length;
}

Comment: Is it possible to view the results page wise like more in unix shell ?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get it by using below :

```
db.CorruptUserAgents.findOne({"_id":"domain.com"}).userAgents.length;
```